# converting list to string and then return

Tags: java

i want to get the list generated in the following code as string before return from the function "LookUpTransaction". what should i do.?

```
public String[] LookUpTransaction() {
        List list=new ArrayList();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("select accountno,details,amount from transaction");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                list.add(rs.getString(1));
                list.add(rs.getString(2));
                list.add(rs.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] strarray = new String[list.size()];
        return list.toArray(strarray);
    }
```

Comment: depends on how you want to form the String. Iterate the list and form the string as required

Comment: So you just want to print it out?

Comment: username @sanchit want to carry the returned string by SOAP to the JSP page

Comment: That happens OUTSIDE of this function, No? This function is fine, it'll return you an array of strings. Now you can do what you want with it aka send it to your JSP page.

Comment: I see only array, not `List`.  Either way, what would you use the resultant `String` for?  I don't see any place that it'd fit unless you want to change the return type of your method...

Comment: By the way,I think you should release jdbc related staff in a finally block to avoid connection leak problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `return Arrays.toString(strarray);` In this case you have to change the return type of your method to `String`. That is your code must be modified as shown below:

```
public String LookUpTransaction() {
        List list=new ArrayList();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("select accountno,details,amount from transaction");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                list.add(rs.getString(1));
                list.add(rs.getString(2));
                list.add(rs.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] strarray = new String[list.size()];
        strarray = list.toArray(strarray);
        return Arrays.toString(strarray);
    }
```

Please note that the `Arrays.toString(strarray)` returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array (`strarray` in your scenario). The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). If you are looking to iterate over the list & concatenating the elements you could try something like this:

```
 public String LookUpTransaction() {
        List list=new ArrayList();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("select accountno,details,amount from transaction");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                list.add(rs.getString(1));
                list.add(rs.getString(2));
                list.add(rs.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String str : list) {
            stringBuilder.append(str);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  List.toArray(), followed by Arrays.toString()

```
String[] y = x.toArray(new String[0]);
Arrays.toString(y)
```